# Как изменить текст и аттрибут текста в svg с помощью js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Всем добра! Имеется такая задача: Есть график нарисованный с помощью svg в этом графике есть подписи вида `<text ...></text>`, необходимо если число отрицательное - покрасить его в красный.
Пробовал через $('text').each(); Но ничего не выходит( айдишники приписать к ним тоже нет возможности.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно перебрать все текстовые элементы в svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('text').each()` отлично работает.

```js
$('text').each(function () {
  if ( +$(this).text() <= 0 ) {
    $(this).attr('fill', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg>
  <text x="0" y="15" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">1</text>
  <text x="0" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">2</text>
  <text x="0" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">11</text>
  <text x="0" y="75" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">-1</text>
  <text x="0" y="95" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">-6</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, и правда работает. Причина просто была в том что график отрисовывается уже после загрузки страницы посредством ajax+js соответственно когда я искал текст на странице его там фактически не было

Answer (score 2):

SVG это XML, **не HTML**.
Чтобы вставить текст нужен textContent

```js
document.querySelectorAll('text').forEach(item => {
  item.textContent = 666
});
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="0" y="15" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">1</text>
  <text x="0" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">2</text>
  <text x="0" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">11</text>
  <text x="0" y="75" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">-1</text>
  <text x="0" y="95" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">-6</text>
</svg>
```